# Select value from two tables if the condition for either table matches

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables `A` and `B` that both have a `ObjectID` column. `A` has an unique column `ColA` among other columns, and `B` has an unique column `ColB` among others.

I want to do a SELECT based on a pair of given values for `ColA` and `ColB` respectively, such that if a value is found in either column, return the value of `ObjectID` in the corresponding table. If both values are found (i.e. one is found in `ColA` and the other is found in `ColB`), return the matching `ObjectID`s in both tables (which may or may not be the same). If no value is found for both columns, return empty/null result.

For example, given the tables as below

```
A
...| ObjectID | ColA |...
        1       123
        3       234
        4       345

B
...| ObjectID | ColB |...
        2      "abc"
        3      "bcd"
        5      "dce"
```

The query should return `(1, 2)` if the given value for `ColA` is `1` and the given value for `ColB` is `"abc"`.

It should return `(3, 3)` if the given value for `ColA` is `234` and the given value for `ColB` is `"bcd"`.

It should return `(4, null)` if the given value for `ColA` is `345` and the given value for `ColB` is `"abcd"`.

It should return `(null, null)` if the given value for `ColA` is `1234` and the given value for `ColB` is `"abcd"`.

Can this be achieved by a *single* query? Or do I need to create a view of the involved columns from both tables, and SELECT using the view? If so, is there any performance consideration as this query may be executed quite often?

Comment: Just to clarify, if the 2 tables are not linked by any keys (i am assuming based in info presented) why would you want to do this in a single query? Also, are the values you look for specific to a table for are both values looked for in each table?

Comment: @Zero, these two tables are linked to a third table using their `ObjectID` column. There is no constraint on where the value comes from. The simplest way of thinking this is: we can easily solve the problem by using two separate SELECT statements. One for Table `A` based on `ColA` and the other for Table `B` based on `ColB`. I just wonder if we can minimize the number of hits to the database by using a single SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use two scalar subqueries (in SQLite, they return NULL when there is no result):

```
SELECT (SELECT ObjectID
        FROM A
        WHERE ColA = ?
       ) AS ResultA,
       (SELECT ObjectID
        FROM B
        WHERE ColB = ?
       ) AS ResultB
```

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, how performing is this method (comparing to doing two separate SELECTs hence two hits to the database) since the query are run very often?

Comment: SQLite is an embedded database, so there is no client/server communication overhead that would make the number of hits important.

Comment: True, there is little communication overhead. But the client still needs to execute two calls vs. one, and for the database itself, it needs to execute two queries vs. one  (as suggested in your answer). Does that make a difference when we scale this execution to millions of times?

Comment: Probably not, but that depends on a lot of details. You have to measure yourself.

Comment: @skyork: Are you going to call the subqueries just like that (in a FROM-less SELECT passing a pair of scalar values as parameters) or are you going to call them in a query on some (potentially large) dataset (which would serve as the source of the values passed to the subqueries)? Depending on that, there might be other (possibly better) options.

Comment: @AndriyM, thoughtful comment. The two tables involved are moderately large (1M+ rows), and `ColA` and `ColB` are indexed for each respective table. I am not using the results for any subquery, am only interested in the results themselves.

Answer (score -1):

it is impossible in terms of relational databases and sql  sql query is a single operation and can return one result of some data combination (if not to speak about any sql programming like cursor, pl/sql, t-sql etc).  As you have to tables and do not want to combine them (and you really don't, you want 2 results of 2 independent manipulations in one query).

possible combinations are:

- cartesian product of tables - result contains each row of A concatenated with every row of B, so no row of A without row of B
- join(inner/outer) -  result contains concatenations of rows of A and B chosen by some conditions (values of some fields in some subsets of two tables shoul be equal)

so

1. it is possible to reach conditions:

   - The query should return (1, 2) if the given value for ColA is 1 and the given value for ColB is "abc".
   - It should return (3, 3) if the given value for ColA is 234 and the given value for ColB is "bcd".

     select a.ObjectID, b.ObjectId from a [full] outer join b on {some alwais false a.x = b.y} where a.colA = v1 and b.colB = v2
2. it my be possible to reach conditions:

   - It should return (4, null) if the given value for ColA is 345 and the given value for ColB is "abcd".

     select a.ObjectID, b.ObjectId from a,b where a.colA = v1 and b.colB = v2
3. it is impossible to reach:

   - It should return (null, null) if the given value for ColA is 1234 and the given value for ColB is "abcd".

because there are no operation in sql, that return all null dataset.

4. it is possible to reach conditions:

   - The query should return (1, 2) if the given value for ColA is 1 and the given value for ColB is "abc".
   - It should return (3, 3) if the given value for ColA is 234 and the given value for ColB is "bcd".
   - It should return (4, null) if the given value for ColA is 345 and the given value for ColB is "abcd".

because cartesian product (cross join)  and  outer joins are mutually exclusive